# mysql crashing on startup after changing the root password

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Recently changed my mysql root password through MySQL Workbench and restarted the mysql service. mysql crashing on startup now. I am not able to bring the service up at all and not sure which log files to refer. following is the error, I get in .err file under data directory. Kindly provide directions to debug and resolve the issue.

```
*140211 15:47:52 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140211 15:47:52  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
140211 15:47:52  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140211 15:47:52  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Error: trying to access page number 4294965503 in space 0,
InnoDB: space name D:\Apps\OrangeHRMS2.7\mysql\data\ibdata1,
InnoDB: which is outside the tablespace bounds.
InnoDB: Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type 10.
InnoDB: If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that
InnoDB: your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the
InnoDB: MySQL server.
140211 15:47:52  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 1076 in file ..\..\..\mysql-5.5.8\storage\innobase\fil\fil0fil.c line 4374
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http: //bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http: //dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
140211 15:47:52 - mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help diagnose
the problem, but since we have already crashed, something is definitely wrong
and this may fail.
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 133447 K
bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
thd: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
005E4EB4    mysqld.exe!?check_next_symbol@Gis_read_stream@@QAE_ND@Z()
The manual page at http: //dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tray this.

1.- stop your services.

in linux service mysqld stop - in Windows net stop MySQL

2.- start your services with "stop grant tables"

mysqld --skip-grant-tables

3.-update the password of user root

$mysql>UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('my_password') where USER='root';

(if you want you can create your user) $mysql>CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

4.- Flush the privilages

$mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

5.- Restart your server

service mysqld start